# xpath xsl find when parent have attribute equal to value

Tags: xml, xslt

These is my xml:

```
<root>
<node>
 <element id='1'>
   <subelement>val</subelement>
</element>
<element id='2'>
   <subelement>val</subelement>
</element>
</node>
```

i don't know the parent name and 'node' name

The solution 
descendant::*[ @id= '1' ]/subelement

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an efficient XSLT solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i don't know the parent name and
>   'node' name
>
> The solution `descendant::*[ @id= '1'
>   ]/subelement`

**Using `descendant::*` can be extremely inefficient** as this causes the complete sub-tree rooted by the current node to be traversed.

**Here is an efficient XSLT solution**:

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kElByParentId" match="*" use="../@id"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy-of select="key('kElByParentId', '1')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<root>
    <node>
        <element id='1'>
            <subelement>val</subelement>
        </element>
        <element id='2'>
            <subelement>val</subelement>
        </element>
    </node>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<subelement>val</subelement>
```

**Do note**: The use of keys (`<xsl:key>` and the `key()` function) makes this a really efficient solution -- with sublinear (even close to constant) time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

This would match the condition in the subject:

```
//element/@id eq //element/subelement/text()
```

But what would you like to do with this? Perhaps you need this to be more generic?

Comment: i don't know the 'element' name

Answer (score 1):

If you know how deep it is then you can just use `*` as in:

```
/*/*/element[@id = '1']/subelement
```